# webcam issue after UV4L installation

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, webcam, uv4l, fswebcam

I am trying to make a usb webcam work on my rpi but it drives my nuts.
I have Rpi 3 model B+
Also I've downloaded the newest raspbian image (stretch with desktop and recommended software). It's updated and upgraded.
At first I installed `fswebcam` and it worked fine until I've installed `uv4l` for webrtc streaming.
Now my webcam just doesn't work.

[image]

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0513:0318 digital-X, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ fswebcam -S 30 test.jpeg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 352x288.
Error mapping buffer 0
mmap: No such device
Unable to use mmap. Using read instead.
--- Capturing frame...
Skipping 30 frames...
Timed out waiting for frame!
Capturing 1 frames...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.
```

[image]

Now I can't test my webcam even with a browser.

`Camera not authorized. Please check your media permissions settings.`

How to repair webcam initialization?

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, sorry, I've updated the post